# microsoft-graph api : Get new access token from refresh token in graph without redirect url

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am making an app that creates an event on behalf of the authenticated user. I am storing both the access token and refresh token in db. How can I use these refresh token to get a new access token and create an event for the user without authenticating again?

Here in the docs, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user, it is taking refresh_token to get a new access token and refresh token. But here, in the required fields they mentioned redirect URL.

I want just new access token to use that token for creating an event. is there any way to get a new access token from refresh token without redirecting to some URL. I want that in the API response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The redirect URI there should be the redirect URI used when you originally authenticated the user. It is part of the protocol, there is no redirect done when refreshing tokens.

Comment: I tried the API. It gave me tokens in response body. Yes, it is part of the protocol, there is no redirect done when refreshing tokens.